# Swapping max and min in matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to swap the largest element with the smallest element in a given matrix but the program swap the wrong values.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int n, m, largest;

    int arr[100][100];
    int swap[100][100];

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    largest = arr[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            swap[i][j] = arr[i][j];
            if (largest < arr[i][j])
            {
                swap[i][j] = arr[j][i];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", swap[i][j]);
            if (j == m - 1)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show a minimal example of input and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: @M. Marayef The code does not make a sense.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything to find the largest or smallest elements. And instead of swapping two elements, it seems to do a partial matrix transpose.

Comment: use both `if` and `else` to find the min and max numbers indexes and replace

Comment: This is the algorithm you need: 1. Find the larget value and store its indexes somewhere. 2. Find the smallest value and store its indexes somewhere. 3. Do the swap. Just the same way you'd do it on paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the indices of minimum element (i min, j_min) and maximum element (i_max,j_max) and you change both values(maximum & minimum) ​​using a temporary variable like this :

Note :you should change 'n' by rows and 'm' by cols

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int rows, cols;
    do
    {
          printf("Give me the number of rows :");
          scanf("%d",&rows);
    }while(rows<1);
    do
    {
          printf("Give me the number of cols :");
          scanf("%d",&cols);
    }while(cols<1);
    int arr[rows][cols];
    printf("\nThe filling of the Matrix :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int i_max = 0,j_max=0;
    int i_min = 0,j_min=0;
    int max=arr[0][0];
    int min=arr[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j]>max)
            {
                max=arr[i][j];
                i_max=i;// i_max mean's the index i of the maximum element
                j_max=j;// j_max mean's the index j of the maximum element
            }
            if(arr[i][j]<min)
            {
                min=arr[i][j];
                i_min=i;// i_max mean's the index i of the minimum element
                j_min=j;// j_max mean's the index j of the minimum element
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nDisplay of the Matrix before the swap :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
             printf("[%d]", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int temp=arr[i_min][j_min];
    arr[i_min][j_min]=arr[i_max][j_max];
    arr[i_max][j_max]=temp;

    printf("\n\nDisplay of the Matrix after the swap :\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d]", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```